# Exchange 2003 HTTP Account Error

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

We are trying to get one of our users connected to our Exchange 2003 server using the HTTP method as they already have an existing Exchange account on another server.

The setup goes through and they appear to get connected fine however none of the subfolders are listed. Instead we get one folder of "Error-Pls file a Bug". The usual Google search just throws up nothing useful.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or has anyone actually gotten Outlook (2003 or 2007) to connect to an Exchange 2003 server?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly "RPC over HTTP" needs to be enabled on the Exchange Server, then configured correctly on Outlook.

This is profile-specific, thus you can connect many different servers.

There's more configuration stuff in there, but that's a good starting point.

Comment: RPC over HTTP is enabled and working fine. Problem we are seeing is not specific to any profile, they are all doing it.

To clarify, we are trying to use the HTTP type account, not the exchange type with the access over http option.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of anyone using that HTTP account type for anything other than hotmail; I'm not sure that's going to work with Exchange.

What I usually do if I need more than one Exchange account in a profile is to use IMAP (with TLS, for both IMAP and SMTP).

Works well and functions fairly close to how a MAPI profile works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the HTTP account type is not valid for Exchange Server. I've never heard or seen any documentation or information that suggests that it is a valid account type for Exchange. I'm with gravyface on setting up the second account to use IMAP (or POP). You could also set up multiple Outlook profiles.